# find sin-1 of user input for ladder hight

Tags: java, math

I'm trying to find the sin of a number that the user inputs say for eg 1.5. I've done it on the calculator and it works but the code is not working.

Here is the code:

```
package msd1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Part3
{     
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {    
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Enter a number");

        double Height = scanner.nextDouble();

        double Angle =  Height/2;

        double asine = Math.asin(Angle);

        System.out.println("Arcsine of " + Angle + " = " + asine);

    }

}
```

Comment: "The code won't" ? Whats that mean? What does it do, but my guess is that you are not using the right units (degrees vs radians)

Comment: Do you want the sine or the arcsine/inverse sine?  If the latter, you should know that its argument isn't an angle, and an input of 1.5 won't give you a real number.

Comment: Are you using degress in the calculator, because in your code you are using radians.

Comment: Can you add the example of the hand calculation in your post so we can see how your code differs?

Answer (score 8):

Your variable names make no sense. A "height" is a length, and dividing a length by 2 doesn't give you an "angle". Furthermore, you don't pass an "angle" to `asin`, you pass it a number from -1 to +1 and it *returns* an angle.

In your case, you'd want to want to take the height of the ladder and divide it by its length to give you your sin (between -1 and +1), then take the asin of that value.

Odds are you also want to take the angle returned by `asin` in radians and convert to degrees.

You might have code like this:

```
double lengthOfLadder = 2.0;
double height = scanner.nextDouble();
double sine = height / lengthOfLadder;
double angleInRadians = Math.asin(sine);
double angleInDegrees = angleInRadians / Math.PI * 180;
```